# Host library project for others to use as dependency in their projects

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to make android dependencies path of my project. For, example I made one library demo for `AnimatedTextView` now I want to use that demo in my other project as compile path like this.

```
dependencies {
       compile 'com.zerocool.animatedtextdemo:AnimatedTextView:1.0'
}
```

I don't know how to make this path. If some one want to use my this library then I don't need to give demo library. Just give this compile path so they can use this. I don't have any idea for this.So suggest me what I have to do...?

Answer (score 2):

To make this work, you need your library in a `repository` that is identified in the `buildscript` like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This creates a reference to a repository where you can put external dependencies. See the documentation here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

For example, if you want to host your own repository, you can create a maven server, add your library and then put this in the gradle.build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
                url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
        } 
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

If you then put your library in the repo at `http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2`, gradle will check that repo when it tries to resolve dependencies and it should find your library.

Note that you can reference multiple repository locations, and some are "well known" so you do not have to specify the URL. There are many ways to "host" your repo, but that is how you allow for the type of behavior that you asked about. See this reference here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories